# Fantasy graphic novel of a medieval world with no adults

Tags: story-identification, comics, childrens-novel, medieval

It's a fantasy graphic novel I read about five years ago, about a medieval fantasy world that, for some reason, has no more adults, so just kids have to deal with everything. Does anyone have a clue on the name?

Some facts I remember:

1. The kids left in the "main kingdom" are struggling for power, because the guy who's king is kind of an abusive-stupid man. Kid.
2. This king formed a party of warriors to go and look for the adults, or something like that, and that's where the adventure begins.
3. One of the kids in this party is related to the previous kings, or previous heroes of the realm... can't quite remember.
4. It was an occidental comic book, not manga.
5. It was all in colours, not B/W.
6. I'd dare to say it was late 90s novel, or close by.

Comment: The scenario sounds very slightly like an episode of "Justice League Unlimited", called "Kid Stuff". Basically, the kid of a very powerful sorceress banished every adult into another realm, basically becoming the king of the world (now populated only by children). And he's a brat.

Comment: @Clockwork - Said episode was based on a two-part series, collected in the trade paperback [*JLA: World Without Grown-Ups*](https://www.comixology.com/JLA-World-Without-Grown-Ups-1998/comics-series/98081); the story was originally published in 1998. Of course, both the TPB and the episode were set in the present day.